# Project Euler #1 Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TOP_LIMIT 1000

float sum_of_series(float start_from,float position,float difference)
{
    return (position/2) * 
        ( 2 * start_from + (position-1) * difference);
}

int find_last_multiple(int limit,int multiplier){
    return limit - (limit % multiplier);
}

void main(void){

    float last_position_3 = 
        find_last_multiple( TOP_LIMIT-1 , 3 ) / 3;

    float last_position_5 = 
        find_last_multiple( TOP_LIMIT-1 , 5 ) / 5;

    float last_position_15 = 
        find_last_multiple( TOP_LIMIT-1 , 15 ) / 15;

    float sum_of_series_3 = sum_of_series(3,last_position_3,3);
    float sum_of_series_5 = sum_of_series(5,last_position_5,5);
    float sum_of_series_15 = sum_of_series(15,last_position_15,15);

    float answer = sum_of_series_3 + sum_of_series_5 - sum_of_series_15;    

    printf("sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000\n");
    printf("answer = %f\n",answer);

}
```

I compiled it with: gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1)

Comment: Does this produce the correct?  My assumption is that you're probably off by 285 or 570.

Comment: got the answer as correct. otherwise I would not post it here.

Comment: Oh, I see the last one subtracts.

Comment: How has noone picked up on `void main(void)`?! Needs to return `int` type, and either don't specify parameters, or `(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: @OllieFord : janos said it didn't work. I'm still a beginner in C. However it did work with the specified compiler

Comment: I'm surprised - but you certainly shouldn't use it. It must be undefined (since gcc actually did let you) and should be avoided. Just use `int main()` until you need any command line options, then the params above. Some advocate always doing `return 0` on success of `main`, but compiler won't complain if `int main` never returns an `int`.

Comment: @OllieFord : If you can please post an answer, If you think it has potential value to the community. IMHO it does and you should post an answer

Comment: [Sum of Arithmetic Sequence](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, your algorithm/solution is clever. It is an \$O(1)\$ solution which I like, when most other solutions would be an \$O(n)\$ and do a modulo on 3 and 5. The trick for subtracting the double-count is something that should have a clear comment, including the reason why.

The `find_last_multiple` is also a neat solution. No issues with that, and it is simple enough to not require a comment.

Unfortunately the `sum_of_series` has some problems.... it should be commented, for a start... the logic is far from obvious.... I have not figured it out... yet.

Also, at this point it becomes `float` based calculations, and that threw me for a second. I immediately started thinking int-based math because the code has int constants, and it does int values in the find_last_multiple but it then does implicit casts to float. Very confusing.

Finally, it makes the assumption that that the series starts from 3, 5, or 15, but the question description starts from somewhere else.... I suggest you discard the starts_from parameter, and simply use the difference instead.

So, using float-based logic, and returning a float based solution is unexpected.... and I would expect there to be some comment as to why the sum of integers in a series is a float.

Finally, your `sum_of_series` should represent the standard formula for the sum-of-a-series (see the [alternate form in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)):

$$
\frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1)d)
$$

where n is the number of terms in the series, a is the start value, and d is the difference.

That can be simplified by setting a to be 0 (eliminating the 2a term), and for int math by doing:

$$
\frac{n(n - 1)}{2}d
$$

Mathematically, any multiple of an even number is always going to be even. Now, either \$n\$ or \$n - 1\$ is even.... so, \$n(n-1)\$ will be even, and safe to divide by 2.

I would also start from 0. Using integer math, the problem is simpler:

```
int sum_of_series(int limit, int difference)
{
    // from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression
    // formula for calculating the sum of a progression from 0 to a 'limit'
    // in steps of 'difference'. e.g. limit 10, difference 2 adds 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 = 30
    int n = 1 + limit / difference; // integer math gives number of terms including term 0
    return ((n * (n - 1)) / 2) * difference;
}
```

So, you can use the above safely as:

```
int sum = sum_of_series(999, 15);
```

which will give the result `15 * (67 * 66) / 2` or  `33165`

Note that the problem statement requires the sum of values less than 1000, and the sum_of_series formula calculates inclusive of the limit, so we use the limit of `999`, not `1000`

Additionally, using the int-based logic, there is no need for there to be the find-limit method at all. This reduces your main method to:

```
int main(void){

    int sum_of_series_3 = sum_of_series(999,3);
    int sum_of_series_5 = sum_of_series(999,5);
    int sum_of_series_15 = sum_of_series(999,15);

    int answer = sum_of_series_3 + sum_of_series_5 - sum_of_series_15;    

    printf("sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000\n");
    printf("answer = %d\n",answer);

    return 0;

}
```

I put the above [together in a working **Ideone**](http://ideone.com/QHGnkv)

Comment: If you omit the 0th term as the problem does, you can also eliminate the \$+1\$ when calculating \$n\$ and use the more standard formula for summing the first \$n\$ positive integers: \$n (n + 1) \over 2\$.

Comment: Your `sum_of_series` function might still be incomplete without a better explanation of the formula or a URL to an explanation of the formula.  I know at this point it's in a form that will be more familiar to mathematicians, and the formulas you included look familiar to me from Calculus.  The average programmer is not a mathematician however and probably unfamiliar with this formula.  Meanwhile, the problem statement is pretty easy to understand for non-mathematicians.  When the code is harder to understand then the problem statement, you need really, really good comments.

Comment: Should probably mention that `void main(void)` is a non-standard signature for C (and C++) since this is code review.

Comment: `The average programmer is not a mathematician however` how sad.

Comment: "The trick for subtracting the double-count is something that should have a clear comment, including the reason why" -- Anyone for whom it isn't obvious upon seeing it is severely broken.

Comment: @Cthulhu The average programmer cannot be above average at everything. I'm a programmer and a mathematician, perhaps it is sad that I'm not a designer, statistician, or system engineer. Or perhaps not. Regardless of how we react emotionally to it, there are many talented engineers that don't have mathematics as one of their strong suits, and I have enjoyed working with some of these.

Comment: @EricWilson No, programmer does not have to be professional mathematician, but programming without mathematical thinking is horrible.

Comment: @Cthulhu I'll disagree. It is limiting, but a programming team can use many types of contributions. If I was unwilling to work with those that don't have  a firm grasp of trigonometry, I would have few employment options.

Answer (score 17):

### What you did well

Using a formula to compute sums is efficient.  Using the inclusion-exclusion principle is smart.  You chose descriptive names for your functions and variables.  The intention is fully clear just from reading this single line:

```
float answer = sum_of_series_3 + sum_of_series_5 - sum_of_series_15;
```

### Concerns

The foray into floating-point is mildly disconcerting, for accuracy and performance reasons.  I say "mildly", since I doubt that it has any real consequences in this particular solution, but I would still consider it bad practice to do integer calculations using floating point.

[image: Homer's false disproof of Fermat's Last Theorem]

### Mathematical expressions

You defined `TOP_LIMIT` as 1000, yet hard-coded 1000 in the format string.  The output will look wrong if you ever need to change `TOP_LIMIT`.

`sum_of_series(start_from, position, difference)` could be clearer, by renaming `position` →  `number_of_terms`, `difference` →  `step`, and maybe also `sum_of_series` → `sum_of_arithmetic_seq`.

A possible simplification is to define more primitive, generically useful functions.

$$\begin{align*}
\underbrace{3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + \ldots + 999}_{n\ \textrm{terms}}\ &= 3\ (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \ldots + n)\\
&= 3 \frac{n\ (n + 1)}{2}
\end{align*}$$

```
int sum_of_1_to_n(int n) {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

int count_multiples_under(int limit, int step) {
    /* Integer division automatically rounds down as necessary */
    return (limit - 1) / step;
}

int main(void) {
    int limit = 1000;
    int sum_of_series_3  =  3 * sum_of_1_to_n(count_multiples_under(limit, 3));
    int sum_of_series_5  =  5 * sum_of_1_to_n(count_multiples_under(limit, 5));
    int sum_of_series_15 = 15 * sum_of_1_to_n(count_multiples_under(limit, 15));

    int answer = sum_of_series_3 + sum_of_series_5 - sum_of_series_15;
    printf("sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below %d = %d\n", limit, answer);
}
```

Comment: `count_multiples_under` is a much better name. all in all, this is much more readable.

Answer (score 10):

As [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl) pointed out, after you rewrite `sum_of_series` to work with integers and return an `int`, you could replace all `float` variables with `int` in the entire program. (And of course, change the last `printf` to use `%d` instead of `%f`.)

---

GCC gives me an error for `void main`, it wants it to return `int`.

---

It's good to avoid `#define` when possible. It would be better to use a global constant instead, or even a local constant in the `main` method. But the program becomes kinda fun if you make this a command line argument, for example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int top_limit = atoi(argv[1]);
    // ...
    printf("answer = %d\n", answer);
}
```

And then when you run it:

```
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 10
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 10
answer = 23
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 100
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 100
answer = 2318
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 1000
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000
answer = 233168
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 10000
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 10000
answer = 23331668
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 100000
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 100000
answer = 2333316668
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 1000000
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000000
answer = 233333166668
$ gcc t.cpp  && ./a.out 10000000
sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 10000000
answer = 23333331666668
```

What the hell, the answer for powers of 10s (beyond 100) seems to always match the regex `23{n}16{m}8` where `m = n - 1`! How cool is that?

(For the larger numbers I had to change some of the `int` types to `long`.)

Comment: About the formula 23{n}16{m}8 its a little bit lengthy but it is not difficult to prove that there is a pattern like that. Eventually you can ask on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

Why a so complicated algorithm when you can keep it as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int sum=0;                                                                                                                                  
  for (int i=1;i<1000;i++) {                                                                                                                  
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)                                                                                                             
      sum += i;                                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                           
  printf("%d\n",sum); // 233168                                                                                                               
}
```

Since you have no input every solution is \$O(1)\$.

Comment: It looks a bit better now... but this solution is actually \$O(n)\$.  It's very similar to a now-deleted answer that received the same criticism.

Comment: There is no \$n\$ in the problem statement.

Comment: It means linear complexity.  This code loops through a certain number.  Constant complexity would involve single operations.  The OP's code *is* \$O(1)\$.

Comment: Executing a couple of operations a thousand of times is \$O(1)\$.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini - you're right, since the input is a constant, all Solutions will be O(1), and there is no concept of scaling at all. Talking time-complexity for scaling is... going to require assumptions. Still, your solution is about 1000 times slower than the OP's

Comment: 1000 times slower means 10 milliseconds on my pc. What about if you take into account the time used to write the program? 

Project Euler only requires to get the right solution, so I think it is much better to have a simple program which one can easily trust upon, than a complicated, difficult-to-check algorithm.

Also consider that this is problem no 1... there will be time to get into complicated algorithms!

Comment: "Project Euler only requires to get the right solution" -- if all the OP cared about is getting the right solution, they wouldn't have written this code and wouldn't have posted it here.

Comment: Project Euler is way more than the right solution. Also, do this,
int n = whateverNumber;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)

Can you see the O(n) now?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea take this code `int n = 4; for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ){ print i }` is this still O(n)? We could easily rewrite it as `print 0`, `print 1`, up to 4 and then you would say it is O(1). In this case it the solution is O(1) because we can rewrite it to be hardcoded.

Comment: @nwalsh yes, it's still O(n). No matter if you hardcode it, you still have 4 operations dude. The main difference is that a loop scale, a hardcoded solution does not.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea However the `n` does not change in this case. Because of the problem we want to find all the values below 1000 that are divisible by 3 and 5. So it is really `const int n = 1000`. It is not a O(n) solution. The difference between OP's code and this solution is that OP's code is O(1) in all cases given size as an input, yet this code is only O(1) if we predetermine the size and not have it specified on input.

Comment: @nwalsh what if I wanted sum(51, 100) - sum(101, 150) + sum(151, 200) ? Will you still hardcode it? Or will you implement the function sum in O(n) -- assuming no formulas?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea We agree that this sum function will be run in O(n) because it takes user specified input. We could indeed implement a function to run in O(1) time if we were wanting to optimize time at all costs. However doing so will result in harder to read code. Personally, I would use the sum function to do the work because it is easier to read (provided I do not care about efficiency).

Comment: If one has a function $f(n)$ which runs in $O(n)$ and computes $f(1000)$ the computation takes constant time.  Of course this tell us nothing, but the fact that we are interested in a single input is something which can be taken into consideration. If I need to write a script to be used once, the time used to write the script is more important than the time used to run it.

Comment: It is interesting to note that this answer is very divisive... seems that it got a lot of upvotes even if the total is zero.

Comment: I just read the pdf file from Project Euler, Seems like even they suggest something similar to my code.